# Adding a qr scanner to a mobile app

Tags: angularjs

I am currently building a mobile app using angularJS, on plunker. The app once complete will be used on iPhone and android devices and will need to be able to access the camera and scan a QR code.

What i'm struggling with is how to go about this. I have done some research and found a lot of github solutions such as -

https://github.com/sembrestels/angular-qr-scanner
https://github.com/blockchain/bc-qr-reader

However I am unsure of how to add these to a plunker built app or if it is even possible?

One idea I have had whilst looking online is to make use of HTML5 and getusermedia to access a devices camera. Although then using this to scan a QR code is quite beyond me.

I am quite new to all this, and if I am honest not very confident at all. Any recommendations will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: if you use Ionic framework...it would be much easier to integrate any native mobile functionalities. see this:   https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/barcode-scanner/

Comment: Edit - Just discovered I can add an external library to plunker.

Comment: I have had a look through Ionic website and spent some time on the creator. But I dont see how I can use these features on the plunker website?

Comment: you can't use that feature on the plunker website because you need an IOS device to scan the QR code....how would you go about scanning the QR code from your desktop? Am I understanding your question correctly?

Comment: Not quite, I am unsure of how to actually add the QR scanner to the plunker website in the first instance.

Comment: you can't add QR scanner to the plunker website....how would you scan a barcode? you need a camera(on a mobile device) to scan a barcode

Comment: you need to deploy the app on the mobile device to test the QR Scanner functionality because it uses the native device camera to scan the barcode

Comment: Sorry I am being unclear. That is my aim. To build the app on plunker, then deploy and test the QR scanner on a mobile device. Once I know it works I can continue building on plunker.